# how to copy div element without losing value

Tags: javascript, html

I have div1 tag with all the required elements and I want to copy the entire element to another div say div2 , but when I do so it loose all the data in the text box's of div1 and than copies it to div2. What is the approach for not loosing the data. here's the code example that I am using:

### HTML

```
     <div id="div1">
     <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="">
     <textarea></textarea>
     </div>
     <div id="div2" style="display:none;">
     </div>

     <input type="button" name="hide" onclick="document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML=document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML">
     <input type="button" name="show" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML">
```

Comment: Not quite sure what do you want to achieve, but you should separate the JS from the HTML.

Comment: question is confusing.what you mean by data in textbox 1?

Comment: You shoul assign div innerhtml to some variable then replace the combined html

Comment: @kiranRS by data I refer to the value of textarea. the data which user will input..

Comment: how it possible user input values to copy to another div? Do one thing , store text area value to a variable and display it where ever it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the contents of the textarea in a variable, then copy your div and insert the contents into the textarea afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Make a 3rd hidden div `< div style = "display:none" >` The div won't be shown on webpage
Copy data from div 1 to div 3, div 2 to div 1, then div 3 to div 2.